# Protractor - Test suite not working if exclude the first "it" block

Tags: protractor

I tried to run my spec.js file as below:

```
describe('my function', function() {

  xit('test 1', function(){
  // my code here
  })

  it('test 2', function() {
  // my code here
  })
})
```

But after execute command

> "protractor conf.js"

there only was a blank browser and no more action.

Can anyone help me on this case

Comment: please show your `protractor.conf.js`

Comment: try to add 

```
it('test 2', function(done) {
  // my code here
done();
  })

```

Comment: @Oleksii: here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zydece8LUe6axKVZG_Ydc2Nm3jpB8-MQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Yash Jagdale: thank you but it does not work

Comment: Is your first test doing setup needed for the following tests? If so a refactor might be necessary.

Comment: @MMansour: the only thing I can think of is "browser.restart()" in beforeeach(). But I need to generate report with screenshot after each test then I have to write browser.restart in beforeeach()

Comment: @LongTranThanhPham Try adding a line to actually navigate to the page you're testing in the beforeEach.